# Hosting on Apache/2.2.22, scan says outdated

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, malware

I am web hosting websites on Apache/2.2.22 and did a security scan.  The scan said the server software is outdated; the web hosting provider says its not outdated and is stable.  Someone uploaded malware to non-www directories.

Could the malware have happened due to the outdated Apache/2.2.22 software?

This is a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Could the malware have happened due to the outdated Apache/2.2.22 software?

Possibly. There are a number of vulnerabilities against version 2.2.22 which are listed here:

- http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-142323/Apache-Http-Server-2.2.22.html

As well as here on Apache's website:

- http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_22.html

But it's much more likely that some software which runs on top of Apache was the point of entry.

#### Outdated?

I would definitely call 2.2.22 outdated. It even shows as much on the Apache download page.

[image: ss1]

Comment: So malware files uploaded to a non-www directory could happen as a reason of an outdated apache?

Comment: @X10nD - yes, if there are directories that are writable by the user that Apache is running under. `/tmp` would be one such directory. But often what happens is that the website is used as a beachhead for leveraging up by attackers. There are methods for coercing the system into doing things once malware has been installed on the www directories.

Comment: But how can a attacker see a non-www directory even though the website is hacked?  This is a shared hosting environment so the attacker would not have seen the non-www directory only by just hacking the website.  Could it be the hacker have gained access via the apache?

Comment: @X10nD - yes, it's entirely possible that they may have gained shell access then at that point. I would say this too, if the VPS provider is lazy about keeping Apache up to date, then how can you be convinced that they are doing their do diligence in keeping other software up to date?

Comment: to make matters worse its shared hosting.

Comment: @X10nD - without knowing more specifics it's impossible to really say more on the topic though, IMO.